# Add a new key in a pickle file

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I want to store data by an iterative way.

how could I add some new keys in an pickle that contain already a  dict ??

For example

> ```
> with open(filename_directory, 'wb') as f:
>     pickle.dump({"a" : 1, "b":2 }, f)
>
> new_dict_ = {}
> for i in range(10):
>     new_dict_ [i] = i
>
> with open(filename_directory, 'a') as f:
>     pickle.dump( update_dict_with_my( new_dict_ ) , f)
> ```

Comment: just read the file & overwrite the old pickle, you cannot append to a pickle file (and certainly not use text mode)

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to append to a pickle file. The pickle format is one binary structure, and if you append to a file containing one structure, at best the rest is ignored at worst you corrupt the existing data.

(it makes not more sense to append to a json file either by the way: in both cases, the new data must be *inserted* in the existing structure, not *appended*)

You could:

- read back the dictionary
- update it with the new values (or the other way round, it has a different effect depending on if there are some shared keys)
- dump it back to disk

like this:

```
with open(filename_directory, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({"a" : 1, "b":2 }, f)

new_dict_ = {i:i for i in range(10)}

with open(filename_directory, 'rb') as f:
    new_dict_.update(pickle.load(f))

with open(filename_directory, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump( new_dict_ , f)
```

to read/update/dump with the new keys being on top priority, read first, update and dump:

```
with open(filename_directory, 'rb') as f:
    new_dict_ = update(pickle.load(f))
for i in range(10):
    new_dict_ [i] = i

with open(filename_directory, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump( new_dict_ , f)
```

note that you may be better off with `json` format if you're planning to serialize basic types in a dictionary. At least the dumped format is readable and even updatable by hand and as noted above, if you try to append to a json file, it doesn't work either, even if it's a text file. There will be at least the `]` or `}` final char that needs moving, adding a coma, etc... forget it).